# Typescript: can alias one module at a higher level in the tree, but not another?

Tags: typescript

I have setup the following module structure:

```
module A.B.C.D {
  var ajaxLibNS = ajaxLibNS || A.B.1;
  var appUtilNS = appUtilNS || A.B.2;
  var appUtil = appUtil || new appUtilNS.AppUtil(); //a class that may be found in module A.B.2

  export class SomeClass implements ISomeInterface {
    //region properties
    private ajaxResponse: ajaxLibNS.IAjaxResponse;
  }
}
```

When I compile, the compiler complains, "error TS2095: Could not find symbol 'ajaxLibNS'"

I don't understand why the compiler does not similarly complain about appUtilNS, as it exists at a similar location (i.e., "two levels up, and one over") in the module hierarchy. Yet, there is no complaint from the compiler and the code where appUtil is created runs just fine.

Can someone enlighten me, please? Thanks!

Comment: look at declaration spaces : http://basarat.github.io/TypeScriptDeepDive/#/declarationspaces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simplified version of what you're seeing:

```
module A {
    export class Foo {}
}

module B1 {
    var f = A.Foo;
    var x = new f(); // OK
    var y: f; // Error, can't find symbol f
}
```

The issue is that in this example, `f` only exists in the *value* namespace. TypeScript has two different kinds of names: types and values. When you write a type annotation, you're looking up in the type namespace; in an expression context, you're looking up in the value namespace. `var` declarations do not contribute to the type namespace.

`import` declarations, though, contribute *both* meanings of the imported name. So, you can write this instead:

```
module B2 {
    import f = A.Foo; // Change 'var' to 'import'
    var x = new f(); // OK
    var y: f; // OK
}
```

Note that the generated code here is identical; this just gets the type name of `A.Foo` into `f`.

Comment: So, I currently assign `var ajaxLibNS` to be equal to itself (if defined) or to A.B.2. If I use the `import` statement, instead, will that handle checking if `ajaxLibNS` is already assigned?

Thanks!